# Jmeter - running multiple threads using different author token

Tags: jmeter, token, thread-synchronization

I have created a thread with three steps to:

1. Access token request: it generates a token to be used in step three. This token is stored in a property

   ${__setProperty(accessToken,${accessToken})}
2. Logon Get request to hit a url
3. Logon Post request, pass some data to the url and I have set the Authorisation header using the Bearer + accessToken (the one generated in first step.

Running a single thread it works, perfect; but when I increase the number of threads, the 3 steps are not running in sequence, maybe I have some Access token before the first Logon Post and I see the token this one is using is not the token generated in the first step, it is the last one generated.

If I set a rump time longer of the total execution time it works, but then I cannot run several threads on parallel.

How can I configure the script to run the threads using the correspondent token generated in step 1 in each Post? How can I different properties or variables to store the token of every thread and use them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are mixing Variables and Properties.

In summary, as per [functions reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

- Variables are per Thread
- Properties are shared accross Threads

So don't use setProperty, just use ${accessToken}

Answer (score 0):

Use property only when you **want** to effect all threads. Otherwise you can save variables in other variable as in [User_Parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) where you put new variable name  the value can be a different variable as `${accessToken}`

> filling in the Variable name in the 'Name:' column. To add a new value to the series, click the 'Add User' button and fill in the desired value in the newly added column.
>
> Values can be accessed in any test component in the same thread group, using the function syntax: ${variable}.